# How to implement roles in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I use [angular2-token](https://github.com/noricohuas/angular2-token) for authorization. I tried to prohibit transition to the page on routing for the user with a certain role.

routes:

```
...
{path: '', component: Test1Component, canActivate: [AuthGuard], canActivateChild: [AuthGuard], 
    children: [
        {path: 'test2', component: Test2Component, data: {roles: ['admin', 'user']}},
        {path: 'test3', component: Test3Component, data: {roles: ['admin']}}
    ]
},
...
```

guard:

```
...
    canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<boolean>|boolean {
        let role = 'user'; 

        let roles = route.data['roles'] as Array<string>;
        if (!roles || roles.indexOf(role ) != -1) return true;
       else {
            this.router.navigate(['']);
            return false;
        }
    }
    ...
```

As a result, the page "test3" not one user can not get even the one who has the role of " admin". The only way to allow access to this page is to add the 'user' role to the routing to the 'admin' role". So here's how to make a ban go to the page if the person does not have the administrator role?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Please clarify your question. Note that your code does never care about the user or its roles.

Comment: @JBNizet What else do I need to do to allow users with the "admin" role to go to the "test3"page?

Comment: First, write a guard that actually gets and checks the roles of the current user. Second, add "admin" to the list of authorized roles to the route.

Comment: @JBNizet I already wrote "guard" question there is an example, but it does not work

Comment: And this guard never gets the user and its roles. It just uses a hard-coded "user" role. Hence my comment. You still haven't clarified your question.

Comment: @JBNizet Okay, can you if it's not difficult for you, to give an example of a "guard" to get and test the role of the current user?

Comment: No, because I have no idea of how your specific application gives access to the current user and its roles.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem might be due to your `AuthGuard`. Your `AuthGuard` need to implement both `CanActivate` and `CanActivateChild` interface.

Also, you need to handle the case of no `data.roles` in your `AuthGuard CanActivate function` because in your route definition, your Test1 component route has no `data.roles`. Does it mean everyone can access to Test1?

Your route is not showing probably because of the above mentioned scenario not handled.

I have created a sample application. Work like charm: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-route.